# How do I inject a string to NetworkStream so that it can be read via XmlReader.ReadAsync in C#?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am reading XML data from the `NetworkStream` like follows.

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { Async = true }))
{
    try
    {                    
         while (await xmlReader.ReadAsync())
         {
         ...
```

I would like to call `stream.Inject("</stop>")` so it can be read in the `while` loop above. I know I would have to write a wrapper class around `Stream` and implement the `Inject` method and override the `ReadAsync` method. However I have no idea how to achieve that. Would someone show me how something like that is done (I just can't imagine where in my `Inject` method the additional string should be added)?

Comment: if you want to stop it prematurely, why not just close the stream (or simulate a closed stream in your wrapper by returning 0 bytes on `Read`) ?

Comment: If I just close the stream in another method via `stream.close()` I am getting an `System.ObjectDisposedException` exception while reading the stream in `xmlReader.ReadAsync()`.

Answer (score -1):

NetworkStream is a Stream so that means you can write any chunk of data into it, including XML  strings. Of course, you have to do some conversion like:

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(longXmlString);
networkSteram.Write(data);
```

Comment: This will not inject the data into the read stream, which is what the OP wants. A `NetworkStream` is actually implemented as a single API over two **unrelated** streams (one input, one output); writing has nothing whatsoever to do with reading. Also: a lot of streams are strictly read-only or write-only; plus even if it wasn't (i.e. a `FileStream` or similar), you would have trashed the position, and possibly overwritten real data. Basically: **don't do this**; this is simply wrong.